# Collection.sort with LinkedList Comparable method already overrided

Tags: java, list, comparable

I tried to sort my `linkedlist` using the `Collection.sort` method and I get this error:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `sort(List<T>)` of type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments `(ListIndiv)`. The inferred type `Individu` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`"

I tried to do some research on it but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

List indiv class:

```
public class ListIndiv extends LinkedList<Individu> 
    implements Comparable<Individu> {
    //some code
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Individu i1, Individu i2) {
        return peek().distance(i1) - peek().distance(i2);
    }
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Individu i1 = new Individu();
        i1.age = 4; i1.couleur_yeux = Color.green;
        Individu i2 = new Individu();
        i2.age = 16; i2.couleur_yeux = Color.blue;
        Individu i3 = new Individu();
        i3.age = 24; i3.couleur_yeux = Color.black;

        ListIndiv li = new ListIndiv();

        li.add(i1);li.add(i2);li.add(i3);

        Collections.sort(li);
    }
}
```

The line

```
Collection.sort(li);
```

is causing the problem.. I have no idea what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should be comparable is not the ListIndividu but the Individu class itself (you are not comparing lists, you are comparing Individus in the list). Move the "Comparable" & related method to your Individu class.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, indeed it should be there. Any idea on how i can get the peek() from the list into the compare now ?

Comment: sort can take a second parameter (a specific comparator). This can make sense in your situation where the list itself is important in the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Let the class `Individu` implement the `Comparable<Individu>` interface in order to make a list of them `List<Individu>` sortable.

```
class Individu implements Comparable<Individu> {
   // implementation here ...
}
```

Then you can create a list assign elements to it and sort it like that:

```
List<Individu> list = // create list as linked list e.g
list.add(i1);
list.add(i2);
Collections.sort(list);
```

If it is not possible for you to change the class `Individu` then you can create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Leave a comment if further information is required.

FYI: [This site gives an overview over the concepts](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) around `Comparable` `Comparator` using small focussed examples.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I've been on this site when looking for an answer, it helped me understand how comparable works. I'll try to get this working only with the Comparable for now and if i'm stuck i'll try the Comparator as you said :)